# NullReferenceException while parsing XML

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, api, xml-parsing

I'm trying to make use of the wikipedia API for a simple school project. I'm trying to parse [this URL](http://bg.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=xml&search=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0&namespace=0&suggest=) using WebRequest to download the source and XElement to parse the data. I'm using the following code

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://bg.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=xml&search=" + text)
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
Dim reader As New StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
Dim elm As XElement = XElement.Load(reader)
If elm IsNot Nothing Then

    Dim a As XElement = elm.Element("Section")

    For Each page As Object In a.Elements("Item")
        Dim title = page.Element("Text").Value
        Dim url = page.Element("image").Value

    Next
End If
```

but I'm getting `NullReferenceException` at the begining of `For Each`. Is this the right way to parse XML document in vbNET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    If elm IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each xe As XElement In elm.Nodes
            If xe.Name.LocalName = "Section" Then
                For Each sxe As XElement In xe.Nodes
                    If sxe.Name.LocalName = "Item" Then
                        Dim title As String
                        Dim url As String
                        For Each n As XElement In sxe.Nodes
                            If n.Name.LocalName = "Text" Then
                                title = n.Value.ToString
                            ElseIf n.Name.LocalName = "Image" Then
                                url = n.@source
                            End If
                        Next
                        Debug.WriteLine(title)
                        Debug.WriteLine(url)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

This can probably be simplified using LINQ, but it is a start.